# Heroku error in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've successfully created a simple app and push it to Heroku.  In the first push I could access the URL correctly.  However, after I've done a change and committed, I get the following error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.  If you are the application
>   owner, check your logs for details.

I've checked the logs using `heroku logs` and the result is the following:

```
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-16T18:15:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-01-16T18:15:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-01-16T18:15:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-16T18:15:12+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET falling-warrior-5337.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-16T18:17:29+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET falling-warrior-5337.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-16T18:22:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-01-16T18:22:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-16T18:22:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 16412 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9

2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:2190:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/category.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:148:in `_default_wrap_model'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:167:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:128:in `inherited'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.

2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-16T18:22:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-01-16T18:22:15+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-01-16T18:22:15+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

I'm under Ubuntu, using **RVM** with **Ruby 1.9.2** and **Rails 3.1** - Running `heroku stack` tells me that the deployment environment is **bamboo-mri-1.9.2**

The app works correctly in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems quite clear. You should add `pg` to your Gemfile, since Heroku uses the postgresql database instead of mysql or sqlite3.